# Remove/Delete all duplicate lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

There are a lot of ways to remove duplicate lines, but I want to leave only the unique lines, and delete all duplicated lines.

From something like this:

```
Duplicate
Duplicate
Important text
Other duplicate
Important text1
Other duplicate
```

To get this:

```
Important text
Important text1
```

There are thousands of lines I need to remove, and the unique lines are just 10-20 mixed with all those duplicate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `^(.+)\R([\s\S]*?)\1$`
Repalce with: `$2`

Make sure you've checked `Regular Expression`, `Case sensitive` but NOT `. matches newline`

Comment: This fails if you have a duplicate within another duplicate since it's possessive. For example, if you added a line at the end that contains the text `Important text`.

Answer (score 4):

I think regex could help, you can first recognize repeated lines with something like this:

```
^(.+)$(?=[\s\S]*^(\1)$[\s\S]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aF3xD0/1)

then remove every occurance of matched fragment in text. However I think Notepad++ don't have such capabilities.

This regex will match only first occurance, and will capture in group the second one. But regex cannot match not-continuous text

Example in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "Duplicate\n" +
                "Duplicate\n" +
                "Important text\n" +
                "Other duplicate\n" +
                "Important text1\n" +
                "Other duplicate";
        String result = test;
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.+)$(?=[\\s\\S]*^(\\1)$[\\s\\S]*)",Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(test);
        while(matcher.find()){
            result = result.replaceAll(matcher.group(),"");
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

with result:

> Important text
>
> Important text1

However if you use `replaceAll()` in Notepad++ with this regex, it should leave only one occurance of given line.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, even in your demo there are still 4 lines left not the 2 important lines. Tried it in notepad++ and seems to do the same thing, deletes the duplicate lines but a copy of the lines is still present.

Found a google chrome extension called "Remove Duplicates", is an addon for google's excel app, and it does the job. Still would be nice to use an regex solution, that addon may not be supported in a few years.

Comment: @FuZzy1 yes, exactly as I wrote in my answer, this is why I presented implementation in Java with workaround, regex just recognize which lines are duplicated

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a unix system and the lines are in a file, then you can open the terminal and execute

```
$ sort -u file.txt > uniqelines.txt
```

If you actually want the duplicate lines to be removed you can run

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: This keeps the duplicate lines in text, which is not what the original question asked

Comment: If you want them removed you can run `$ sort file.txt | uniq -u` which will have duplicate lines removed